# Smooth a scatterplot3D graphs using Rstudio

Tags: plot, graph, 3d, smoothing, scatter3d

I have generated the following plot:

Using the following code:

```
par(bg="white")
Y10= scatterplot3d(WF$`YEAR 1`, WF$ST, WF$D1, grid=TRUE, xlim=c(1,10),ylim=c(0,120),type = "h", pch=".", bg="black" ,xlab="YEAR", ylab="Sales Turnover", zlab="Distribution", color="#80FFFFFF", main = "Corp Behavior, Sales Turnover", angle=55)
Y10$points3d(WF$`YEAR 2`, WF$ST, WF$D2 , col="#99FFFFFF", type = "h", pch=".")
Y10$points3d(WF$`YEAR 3`, WF$ST, WF$D3 , col="#B3FFFFFF",type = "h", pch=".")
Y10$points3d(WF$`YEAR 4`, WF$ST, WF$D4 , col="#CCFFFFFF",type = "h", pch=".")
Y10$points3d(WF$`YEAR 5`, WF$ST, WF$D5 , col="#E6FFFFFF",type = "h", pch=".")
Y10$points3d(WF$`YEAR 6`, WF$ST, WF$D6 , col="#FFE6FFFF",type = "h", pch=".")
Y10$points3d(WF$`YEAR 7`, WF$ST, WF$D7 , col="#FFCCFFFF",type = "h", pch=".")
Y10$points3d(WF$`YEAR 8`, WF$ST, WF$D8 , col="#FFB3FFFF",type = "h", pch=".")
Y10$points3d(WF$`YEAR 9`, WF$ST, WF$D9 , col="#FF99FFFF",type = "h", pch=".")
Y10$points3d(WF$`YEAR 10`, WF$ST, WF$D10 , col="#FF80FFFF",type = "h", pch=".")
```

I wish to smooth the graphs that I obtain, to get something more viewable/beautiful to see.

If someone has a suggestion, I'll be very happy.
Also, if you have suggestion to improve the code that I've made, I'll be also glad.

Thanks everyone !

Comment: I don't know why the plot doesn't appear, basically, it gives 10 different distribution